# How to send an image through SOAP without going out of memory?

Tags: java, android, memory, soap, heap-memory

I'm trying to send images from my HTC Explorer through SOAP.
The problem is that I'm getting the heap memory error.

> 02-06 12:54:34.638: D/dalvikvm(29895): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 42% free 9815K/16711K, external 616K/4666K, paused 32ms
>   02-06 12:54:34.688: E/dalvikvm-heap(29895): Out of memory on a 4177936-byte allocation.

The phone where I'm testing the App have 20MB of heap and the image is a very large one (~4MB).

I'm doing the work to the image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
bitmap.recycle();
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

try {
    stream.close();
    stream = null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
byte_arr = null;
```

....
Then I put the string in a property for an request to the envelope and I send the envelope
...

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

The error happens in this last line, because this asynctask (doing this work) exceeded the heap size.

Anyone knows how to send images without going out of memory?

This was the last GC before the error.

> 02-06 12:54:34.638: D/dalvikvm(29895): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 42% free 9815K/16711K, external 616K/4666K, paused 32ms
>   02-06 12:54:34.688: E/dalvikvm-heap(29895): Out of memory on a 4177936-byte allocation.